# Solution for Undefined variable or class error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, undefined-variable

Suppose I have 2 file. One for train and test and the other is a function. In the trainingAndTesting.m file, when I run it then it shows error that:

```
Undefined variable "featuresIdiap" or class "featuresIdiap.trainGenuine"
```

But in the "featuresIdiap.m" file, the function "featuresIdiap" is there and "trainGenuine" is also there in this file. Still it's showing error that it's not defined.

In the trainingAndTesting.m file where it showed the error:

`Idiap_TrainData = [featuresIdiap.trainGenuine; featuresIdiap.trainReplay; ];`

In the featuresIdiap.m file:
The 1st line shows that it has the function "featuresIdiap".

Here's the code:

`function featuresIdiap = featuresIdiap(iterCntIdiaptrain, iterCntIdiaptest,  varargin )`

Then the code where "trainGenuine" is written:

`trainGenuine = zeros( 60*numFrames, numTotalFeatures );`

Another line contains that:

`featuresIdiap.trainGenuine = trainGenuine;`

If I change trainingAndTesting.m file like this:

`featuresIdiap = feature_Idiap([],[]);
Idiap_TrainData = featuresIdiap.trainGenuine;`

Then it shows the following error:

[Undefined function or variable 'getmapping'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7UDe.png)

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I understand that you have:

**File `feature_Idiap.m`:**

```
function featuresIdiap = feature_Idiap(iterCntIdiaptrain, iterCntIdiaptest, varargin)
featuresIdiap.trainGenuine = zeros( 60*numFrames, numTotalFeatures );
```

**File `trainingAndTesting.m`:**

```
Idiap_TrainData = featuresIdiap.trainGenuine;
```

This example here contains everything needed to reproduce your problem. I've removed everything else from the files. This is what is called a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example* (MCVE), the Help Center has a very nice [description of this process](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), next time please follow it. If you had posted this from the start, you would have gotten an answer in 5 minutes, as everyone following the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag would have recognized the problem right away! And, honestly, you might have discovered the problem yourself as well.

When you run `trainingAndTesting`, the function `feature_Idiap` is never called. You immediately try to use its output argument. If I modify the MCVE example like this:

```
featuresIdiap = feature_Idiap([],[]);
Idiap_TrainData = featuresIdiap.trainGenuine;
```

then the error goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have changed the file name as you have said "featuresIdiap.m", still the error is same. Right now in this file at the top it's written like this: 
"function featuresIdiap = feature_Idiap(iterCntIdiaptrain, iterCntIdiaptest, varargin )"
If I change it to like this:
"function featuresIdiap = featuresIdiap(iterCntIdiaptrain, iterCntIdiaptest, varargin )"
Still the error is same.

Comment: Thanks.
But "trainGenuine" is not a function. 

In the  trainingAndTesting.m file, it's called like this:

Idiap_TrainData = [featuresIdiap.trainGenuine; featuresIdiap.trainReplay; ];

And in the featuresIdiap.m file, it's used like this:
trainGenuine = zeros( 60*numFrames, numTotalFeatures );

featuresIdiap.trainGenuine = trainGenuine;

What I understand it's clearly defined in featuresIdiap.m file, am I right? So where is the mistake? Can you please tell after seeing this?

Comment: Please have a look at the question now. I've modified it. Please ignore my mistake and help me with some better answer.

Comment: Please check the edited question. When I use the code you give then it's showing this new error. I've attached the screenshot of the error. Hope it will help you to understand more easily.

Comment: @RezwanhasanAntik: Really, you have to implement your own solution here. I'm pointing out the problem. You need to call the `feature_Idiap` function and capture its output, you cannot use this output without first calling the function. I would think this is obvious. The code I show in the answer fixes the error message *for the MCVE*. You have to adapt this answer to your own code. In particular, you need to call `feature_Idiap` with the right arguments. I have no idea what this function does or needs, I cannot tell you what input arguments it needs. This is up to you.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot for your precious time